# How to display our own desktop on another machine in Linux?

Tags: linux, screensharing, fedora16, desktop-sharing

Suppose, I am a teacher and I am writing code on my machine. The same desktop should get displayed on all the computers being used by students. The Operating System being used is Fedora 16. Please tell me if anyone is known about any utility in fedora 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try vncviewer.  There are a lot of vnc clients.   I used tigervnc when I was studying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this instructions to share your desktop in fedora:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User_Guide_-_Sharing_Your_Desktop

If it doesn't work try installing [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It didnt work for me. I have followed all the steps given in the doc.   Is there any inbuilt utility in Fedora or any other Linux?

Comment: that was the built-in method, try installing teamviewer

Comment: The builtin method solved my problem..